# How to kill audiodg.exe process by programming ways?

Tags: c++, windows, process

How to kill audiodg.exe process by programming ways?

the best programming ways is cpp.

Comment: Google it, and you will get the answer.

Comment: Why do you think you need to kill it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [TerminateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For that you need a process [handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and in turn that requires a process ID (PID) which can be retrieved from the process name by [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526749/get-a-process-id-from-process-name).
TerminateProcess() requires PROCESS_TERMINATE (0x0001) as access rights.